# Restart jboss as 7 programmatically

Tags: jboss7.x, restart

I'm able to restart JBoss AS 7.2.0 Final using Jboss CLI with the following command:

```
jboss-cli.bat --connect --controller=IP:9999 --command=:shutdown(restart=true)
```

Now i need to do it programmatically from a java class, i've tried using the Jboss cli API, here after my code, but it only performs a shutdonw and doesn't restart!

```
CommandContext ctx = null;
try {
  ctx = org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContextFactory.getInstance().newCommandContext();
  ctx.connectController(IP, 9999);

  ctx.handle(":shutdown(restart=true)");

} catch (CommandLineException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really is no JBoss AS 7.2.0.Final but I tested the following on WildFly 8 and JBoss EAP 6.x and it worked for me. Note that port `9990` is used in WildFly and port `9999` is used for JBoss EAP 6.x.

```java
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (final ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9990)) {
        final ModelNode op = Operations.createOperation("shutdown");
        op.get("restart").set(true);
        client.execute(op);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me too. Just to make a precision, i think that JBoss AS 7.2.0.Final is equivalent to EAP 6.1.0.Alpha1.